# How to resume activity with audio in Android?

Tags: java, android, media-player

I have implemented media player. I have only one Activity. When I'm starting the activity, my music starts to play and when I press the back button the music clip is in pause state, and again when I resume my activity, the music resumes properly. But there is error after I try to resume my Application after song got over. The app crashed, and I'm getting exception for `IllegalStateException` in back-press method( `mp.pause();`).

Please have a look at below code and suggest if I am doing something wrong.

```
public class Audio_Activity extends Activity 
{
    private  MediaPlayer mp;
    Button btnStartStop ;

    int length;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    ImageView imgVw;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.audio);
        init();
        imgVw.setImageResource(R.raw.teddy_two);

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        mp=MediaPlayer.create(Audio_Activity.this,R.raw.ennamo_yadho);
        Log.e("Song is playing","in  Mediya Player ");
        Log.e("Current ","Position -> " + length);
        mp.setLooping(false);
        mp.start();
        btnChapter.setEnabled(false);

        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
                btnChapter.setEnabled(true);
                System.out.println("Music is over and Button is enable !!!!!!");
            }
        });
    }

     @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

            // Checks the orientation of the screen
            if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
                Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

     @Override
     public void onPause()
     {
          super.onStop();

          SharedPreferences. Editor prefsEdit = prefs.edit();

          int position = mp.getCurrentPosition();
          prefsEdit.putInt("mediaPosition", position);
          prefsEdit.commit();
        }

     @Override
        protected void onResume() 
        {
            super.onResume();
            System.out.println("Activity is Resume !!!");

                  int position = prefs.getInt("mediaPosition", 0);
                  mp.seekTo(position);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) 
        { 
            if(mp!= null)
            {
                f(mp.isPlaying())
                {
                    mp.pause();
                }
            }
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Here is my Log Cat

```
07-09 11:52:01.057: I/System.out(6854): Music is over and Button is enable !!!!!!
07-09 11:52:03.297: D/AndroidRuntime(6854): Shutting down VM
07-09 11:52:03.297: W/dalvikvm(6854): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-09 11:52:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(6854): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 11:52:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(6854): java.lang.IllegalStateException
07-09 11:52:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(6854):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
07-09 11:52:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(6854):     at com.audio_demo.Audio_Activity.onKeyDown(Audio_Activity.java:203)
07-09 11:52:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(6854):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2609)
07-09 11:52:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(6854):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2375)
07-09 11:52:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(6854):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1847)
07-09 11:52:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(6854):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3701)
07-09 11:52:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(6854):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3651)
07-09 11:52:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(6854):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2818)
07-09 11:52:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(6854):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 11:52:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(6854):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 11:52:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(6854):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-09 11:52:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(6854):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 11:52:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(6854):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-09 11:52:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(6854):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-09 11:52:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(6854):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-09 11:52:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(6854):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 11:52:28.787: I/Process(6854): Sending signal. PID: 6854 SIG: 9
```

Comment: A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough!

Comment: I'm not sure if you're saying the error is in `onBackPressed` or `onResume`, but try putting your `mp.pause()` in `onPause()` and `mp.start()` in `onResume()`

Comment: do you have play/pause button?(do you handle play/pause of song on any button? )

Comment: yes i had done play and pause/resume song on button .But There is one more error @After I try to resume my Application when song get over it got crashed why so?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main  ,  java.lang.IllegalStateException at android.media.MediaPlayer._pause(Native Method) at android.media.MediaPlayer.pause(MediaPlayer.java:1051) And E/AndroidRuntime(5075):  at com.audio_demo.Audio_Activity.onKeyDown(Audio_Activity.java:205).

Comment: Can any one help me please ?

Comment: Paste full stack trace

Comment: I have paste log cat error.Please solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

As I Understand the problem is about mp.seekTo(posiotion) in onResume() or mp.getCurrentPosition in onPause() method. That exception can because of not initializing the media player. According to the listener when the song finished you make your player stop and released and in onResume on line mp.seekTo(position) caused that exception. Remove mp.release() line in OnCompletion() method and in onResume and onpPause methods.
There's another thing you need to do. use a boolean value in your code to understand whether your mediaplayer finished playing or not. Change your onCreat like below:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.audio);
        init();
        imgVw.setImageResource(R.raw.teddy_two);

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        mp=MediaPlayer.create(Audio_Activity.this,R.raw.ennamo_yadho);
        Log.e("Song is playing","in  Mediya Player ");
        Log.e("Current ","Position -> " + length);
        mp.setLooping(false);
        mp.start();
        prefsEdit.putInt("mediaplaying", true);
        prefsEdit.commit();
        btnChapter.setEnabled(false);

    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.stop();
            prefsEdit.putInt("mediaplaying", false);
            prefsEdit.commit();
            btnChapter.setEnabled(true);
            System.out.println("Music is over and Button is enable !!!!!!");
        }
    });

     @Override
     public void onPause()
     {
          super.onStop();

          SharedPreferences. Editor prefsEdit = prefs.edit();
          boolean isPlaying=prefs.getBoolean("mediaplaying",false);
          if(isPlaying){
              int position = mp.getCurrentPosition();
              prefsEdit.putInt("mediaPosition", position);
              prefsEdit.commit();
          }
        }

     @Override
        protected void onResume() 
        {
            super.onResume();
            System.out.println("Activity is Resume !!!");
            boolean isPlaying=prefs.getBoolean("mediaplaying",false);
            if(isPlaying){
                int position = prefs.getInt("mediaPosition", 0);
                mp.seekTo(position);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Still my app is not running properly. Music is over and Button is enable !!!!!!
07-09 12:36:43.748: E/MediaPlayer(7528): Error (-38,0)
07-09 12:36:43.748: E/MediaPlayer(7528): stop called in state 0
07-09 12:36:43.748: E/MediaPlayer(7528): error (-38, 0)

Comment: Thank you Mohamad. I have run successfully.Thanks a lot you for cooperates.